# Unusual Friedel–Crafts alkylation with pivaloyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, carbocation

In class we were told of an anomalous Friedel–Crafts reaction with a tertiary acid chloride — $\ce{(CH3)3CCOCl}$, or pivaloyl chloride. When this reacts with benzene in the presence of $\ce{AlCl3}$, instead of effecting the normal acylation, it instead breaks down into the *tert*-butyl carbocation, which then alkylates benzene to form *tert*-butylbenzene.

I could find no satisfactory explanation for this, however, except for the fact that a tertiary carbocation is a very stable carbocation — and nor did I find any mention of this reaction on searching. Could anyone please detail this further?

Comment: As many reasons already mentioned in previous answers. I also have one reason in mind. I think we can also say that as CO is released, with the evolution of gas , entropy of the reaction increases which makes it more favourable to occur.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You were on right path; *tert*-butyl carbocation is quite stable$\ldots$ so stable that the acylium cation, which normally reacts as an electrophile itself, instead decomposes via decarbonylation (loss of stable carbon monoxide molecule).

[image: Generation of t-butyl cation from pivaloyl chloride with Lewis acid]

The *t*-butyl carbocation isn't as stable as the acylium cation (which is [stabilised by resonance](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41162/why-is-the-acylium-ion-stable)), but the difference is small enough that with the help of the non-reversibility of CO loss (which is removed from the mixture as a gas) and reduction of the steric strain (which is lower in *t*-butyl than in acylium), it is enough to make it the main reaction route instead of a side route.

Comment: Is there any other similar reaction which you know of?

Comment: @Charles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayashi_rearrangement, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Meerwein_rearrangement

Comment: Does the rearrangement in the question asked also have a name?

Comment: It's not a rearrangement but F-C alkylation, only using unusual reagent.

Comment: What is the major product? Once tert-butyl benzene is formed, the ring is more activated towards substitution

Comment: @schrodinger_16 I'd expect some 1,4-bis(tert-butyl)benzene, but tert-butyl benzene should be main product if C6H6 is used in excess.

Comment: @Mithoron Why is acylium cation more stable than tert-butyl cation, exactly?

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41162/why-is-the-acylium-ion-stable

Comment: Only one example or do all such tertiary compounds giving stable carbonation give similar reaction?

Comment: @user137644 You mean if there's another tertiary group instead of t-butyl, there's gonna be similar effect? Yeah, it could be more or less pronounced, depending on bulky it is and how well is cation stabilised.