# Esterfication of 2,2,2-triphenylethanoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

> Explain the formation of (1,1,1-triphenylmethyl)methyl ether when a solution of 2,2,2-triphenylethanoic acid in concentrated sulfuric acid is poured in methanol.

I cannot figure out where is one carbon atom lost. Has it escaped as $\ce{CO2}$? Or is there something more strange happening.

I wouldn't call this reaction an esterification. There is no ester functional group in the final compound.

I guess there's some special role of the three phenyl groups but I'm unable to come up with any mechanism. I hope dehydration is involved as one of the reaction steps.

Comment: Similar thing as [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38454/anomalous-friedel-crafts-acylation-with-tertiary-acid-chlorides)

Comment: Note that the name “2,2,2-triphenylethanoic acid” is not wrong but the preferred IUPAC name is triphenylacetic acid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: The question has pretty much been answered in the comments. I'm just making it substantial.

[image: mechanism]

The **triphenylacetic acid** is dehydrated in the presence of concentrated sulfuric acid to give an acylium ion, namely **triphenylacetylium cation**, which is stabilized by resonance.

Then, the triphenylacetylium cation undergoes decarbonylation (removal of carbon monoxide) to give **triphenylmethyl cation**, which is stabilized by the three phenyl groups.

The oxygen in methanol acts as a nucleophile to attack the carbocation, and is deprotonated to give our desired product **triphenylmethyl methyl ether**.

It is noted that this reaction should be done in a well-ventilated area because of the evolution of toxic carbon monoxide gas.

Comment: The answer is great, but it could benefit more from explaining why the regular esterification does _not_ take place. Is it the minor product? Or does it not take place at all? why?

Comment: Esterification doesn't happen because of steric hindrance - its intermediate has much bigger functional group then acylium. Also, decarbonylation is irreversible and carbocation heavily stabilised.