# The main difference between using AlCl3 and FeCl3 in Friedel-Crafts alkylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

> What is the main difference between using $\ce{AlCl3}$ and $\ce{FeCl3}$ in Friedel-Crafts alkylation?

Is that $\ce{FeCl3}$ disfavors carbocation rearrangement in Friedel-Crafts alkylation?

[image: Friedel-Crafts alkylation of benzene]

Comment: This question is similar to yours: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135259/alkylation-of-benzene/135262#135262

Comment: AlCl3 polarises stronger than FeCl3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alkylation of benzene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135259/alkylation-of-benzene)