# How many times does substitution happen here?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation, electrophilic-substitution, acylation

(This question is from a dubious source)

[image: Friedel-Crafts Acylation of benzene with 1-chloro 2,2-dimethyl propanone]

The reaction taking place here is Friedel-Crafts acylation of benzene with 1-chloro 2,2-dimethyl propanone (pivaloyl chloride?). To me, the options seem most peculiar. When the $\ce{C} - \ce{Cl}$ is broken, it gives rise to a carbocation at the carbon of $\ce{C}=\ce{O}$ bond.

According to my teacher, $\ce{C+}=\ce{O}$ now leaves with the electrons of the adjacent $\ce{C}-\ce{C}$ bond, giving rise to a stable tertiary butyl carbocation. This leads us to $\ce{PhCMe3}$.

Edit 2: this is the same reaction: [Unusual Friedel–Crafts alkylation with pivaloyl chloride](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38454/unusual-friedel-crafts-alkylation-with-pivaloyl-chloride)

Considering that the *t*-butyl group is *para*-directing, the options still don't seem right to me. If this conversion to a *t*-butyl carbocation happens once, can it not happen again? Would we simply not get two *t*-butyl groups *para* to each other?

(I still doubt multiple substitution is even possible)

***Edit 3**: as of 24/2/2024 this question has been confirmed to be of poor quality. See reasons in comments.*

Comment: According to the person who gave me this question, the answer is B.

Comment: tBu group is similar to Me and electron-donating and so activating and p-directing

Comment: See the answer to this SE question  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38454/unusual-friedel-crafts-alkylation-with-pivaloyl-chloride

Comment: @Waylander thanks, that's the same reaction - but it concludes with only tert-butyl benzene.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you would get at least some of the 1,4-di-tert-butyl benzene in the reaction mixture, possibly the major component. The acylium species is not going to stop being a source of tBu+ and the t-Bu-benzene is more activated than benzene itself.

Comment: All right, my teacher confirms this is a poor question. The alternatives listed as the possible products are all incredibly minor.

Comment: You'd get pretty much zero C, little D, but if you got B, then A would also be present and I second what Waylander said.